# RSPec: Fix "warning: already initialized constant" for memoized class under test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I keep seeing these warnings when running this basic test suite:

```
spec/example_spec.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant DB_ID                                                  
spec/example_spec.rb:6: warning: previous definition of DB_ID was here
spec/example_spec.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant FIELDS
spec/example_spec.rb:8: warning: previous definition of FIELDS was here
```

Here's an example test:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe MyModule::BaseClass do
  let(:example_class) do
    Class.new(described_class) do
      DB_ID = 'example'

      FIELDS = {
        a: 2,
        b: 4,
        c: 6
      }

      def foo
        'foo'
      end

      def bar
        'bar'
      end
    end
  end

  subject { example_class.new }

  it 'does foo' do
    expect(subject.foo).to eq('foo')
  end

  it 'does bar' do
    expect(subject.bar).to eq('bar')
  end
end
```

The warnings are triggered anytime I use `subject`.

My understanding is that [`let`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) defines a memoized helper method so that the `example_class` is only evaluated once on first reference.

If that's true, why am I receiving these warnings?

Comment: The value will be cached across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples. From your docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let. So that it evaluates again in every test.

Comment: How does `MyModule::BaseClass` look like?

Comment: `MyModule::BaseClass` has a few methods defined, but not `DB_ID` or `FIELDS`.

Comment: Perhaps I could solve this with `before(:all) { @subject = example_class.new }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you use `Class.new` you are creating an anonymous (unnamed) class.
2. When constant is defined ruby needs to resolve the namespace for which the constant is defined.

Unlike in a module or a class the namespace within the anonymous class is empty.

```
class A
  p Module.nesting # => [A]
  B = 1
end
B    #=> NameError: uninitialized constant B
A::B #=> 1

Class.new(A) do
  p Module.nesting # => []
  C = 1
end
C #=> 1
```

Since there is no explicit namespace where to put these constant, they end up getting defined "globally" in `Object` class.

You can try this yourself with following example (run it with `--order defined`):

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

class Base
end

RSpec.describe Base do
  context 'creating an anonymous class with a constant' do
    let(:example_class) do
      Class.new(described_class) do
        DB_ID = 'example'

        def foo
          'foo'
        end
      end
    end

    it 'does foo' do
      expect(example_class.new.foo).to eq('foo')
    end
  end

  context 'the constant is on Object' do
    it 'does bar' do
      expect(DB_ID).to eq('example')
    end
  end
end
```

It boils down to how ruby constant lookup works. Here is a nice post about it https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html.